# bytearray отказывается принимать кодировку 'uint8'

Tags: python, изображения, opencv, numpy

Хочу выводить картинку,на которую дана ссылка ВК в окне. Но при попытке преобразовать картинку функцией `bytearray`, она отказывается видеть кодировку `uint8`.

```
import cv2
import bs4
import requests
import numpy as np

request = requests.get('https://vk.com/id1?z=photo1_456317315%2Falbum1_136592355')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
soup = soup.find('a', {'class': 'mva_item'})
pic_link = soup['href']
pic_array = np.asarray(bytearray(pic_link,'uint8'), dtype='uint8')
pic = cv2.imdecode(pic_array, -1)
```

Пример взял [отсюда](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/02/convert-url-to-image-with-python-and-opencv/),и немного его преобразовал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pic_link` - это ссылка на картинку, а не сама картинка:

```
In [106]: print(pic_link)
https://sun6-2.userapi.com/c846021/v846021265/4645a/JDTxN_vYfSM.jpg
```

OpenCV умеет открывать картинки по ссылке:

```
ret,img = cv2.VideoCapture(pic_link).read()
cv2.imshow('', img)
```

PS булевая переменная `ret` будет содержать `True` если функция `.read()` успешно прочитала кадр (`frame`), иначе - `False`.

Comment: скажи пожалуйста,что за 'ret' в первой строчке? за что эта переменная отвечает?

Comment: @PythonNewbie, дополнил ответ